# Ado.Net Api Query DTO

Tags: asp.net, api, ado.net, dto

I want to return a DTO from a query and it does not return anything.
I don't know if I have done it right but the where condition exists.

```
    public class ServiciosComandasController : ApiController
    {
        private TPVRestauranteEntities db = new TPVRestauranteEntities();

        // GET: api/ServiciosComandas
        public async Task<IQueryable<ServicioComandaDTO>> GetAsync()
        {
            var ServicioComandaDTO = from s in db.Servicios
                                     where s.Mesas.Ocupada == false
                                     select new ServicioComandaDTO()
                                     {
                                         ID = s.ID,
                                         NumeroMesa = s.Mesas.Numero,
                                         FechaModificacion = s.Pedidos.OrderByDescending(p => p.FechaModificacion).FirstOrDefault<Pedidos>().FechaModificacion,
                                         Pendientes = s.Pedidos.Where(p => p.Comidas.Categorias.Encargado == "Cocina").Count()
                                     };

            return ServicioComandaDTO;
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I did not have a "Servicio" created